# pdfkit with google web fonts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, wkhtmltopdf, pdfkit, google-webfonts

I'm trying to create a pdf with [PDFKit](https://github.com/jdpace/PDFKit) from a webpage with custom [Google Web fonts](http://www.google.com/webfonts#ChoosePlace%3aselect).

I can't seem to get the custom fonts to work properly.
I'm using the default PDFKit middleware for Rails, as shown [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit).

Can someone please show me a .html file and the (preferably ruby) code that converts it to a pdf using PDFKit or just wkhtmltopdf. The converted pdf should have pretty fonts :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We just had the same problem with wicked_pdf, which uses wkhtmltopdf, too. Our solution was to download the font and install them on the machines, which generate the pdfs. Then use the fonts like every other system font.

Comment: Yes, this is what I ended up doing. For the record, the more serious problem turned out to be that for some typefaces Google Web Fonts only supply the .woff version, with no .ttf / .eof / .svg versions. I got fonts from fontsquirrel.com

Comment: @iGel Any chance you can provide the final code on this? A Gist perhaps would be greatly appreciated. Having the same issue getting fonts into PDFKit

Comment: +1 Same solution works for Font Awesome, since it's just web fonts also.